# how price comparison websites works? and how to get data?

Tags: php, laravel, comparator, analysis, price

So I have this project in mind,
**Price comparator** for car rental companies, in my country!
the problem that I am facing right now the majority of this enterprises don't have online rental services or an API that I could pull up the data from, I wanna do something like carrentals.com, search for the location and rent date and the drop off date and search the available cars to rent.

now my main question is that I don't know how I'll get the data, do i need to go to every rental service in my city to get their data or there is something else that i could do!?

Comment: Do a search for `web scraping`

Comment: The rental companies don't have a website with available cars and prices to scrape their data

Comment: If there is no website or social media page, there is no way to automatically update these prices and you would have to do this manually.

Comment: @JerodevI've thought that i would give the companies a spreadsheet to populate it with the data and then upload them to my database?

Comment: Then you will have to do price spying like the grocary stores are doing. They pay someone lousy money to visit stores and register prices. You can of course do the price checking yourself, but depending on your budget some kind of service like this may be more worth it than wasting your own time on it ^^

Comment: Price comparators often allow companies to upload XMLs with needed data. Company owners usually want to be included in aggregators to attract more customers. Maybe talk with biggest rental companies to provide you with data (help them do it), and smaller companies will join too on their own. Making scrapers would be hard for many websites.

Comment: @Volvox thanks i think that is the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can consider top 5 websites in your city, and create a web crawler for them. It would basically be scraping data off their websites. That's what I would've done.

Every website changes it designs sometime so you would have to cater your web crawler according to their design. I had a similar task once and had to create a web crawler for most used websites for their products, similar products, brands and prices. Hope i helped.

Comment: i've think of this solution but here in my country the car rental companies don't have website with the available cars! or an API

Comment: @Yoelji they would most probably be having facebook or twitter pages, right? You can easily learn about the facebook graph explorer api, the data of the pages can be easily read and you can derive average prices from there.

Comment: Is this how websites like Compare the Market and Money Supermarket work or do they call external APIs for each customer request? +1.